# WPF ContentControl not showing user control (which should be bound by DataContext)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentcontrol

I have a UserControl which contains a ContentControl, which in turn should present a UserControl depending on the view model which is set as DataContext.

The XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pcViewModels:SystemPCViewModel}">
        <controls:SystemPCControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pcViewModels:ChipPCViewModel}">
        <controls:ChipPCControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- Left out other definition, I guess you get the point -->
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="Aqua">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Background="Blue">

        <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding CurrentContent}"/>

    </ScrollViewer>

    <StackPanel 
        Grid.Row="1"
        Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

        <Button 
            Width="150" Height="50"
            Content="Configure"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Command="{Binding CurrentContent.ConfigureCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

I made the backgrounds of the Grid and ScrollViewer ugly visible just to be sure it was visible. So that's all visible, I can see that the view model is as DataContext (the button is also working fine).

I used a ContentControl before, and to all my knowledge exactly like this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the [Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) property of your [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.aspx). You can do either of the following:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding CurrentContent}" Content="{Binding}" />
```

or

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentContent}" />
```